# Добавить класс родительскому элементу при наличии класса у дочернего

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такая [структура меню](https://jsfiddle.net/jnscLfjh/):

```
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-active-sub-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

По условию, необходимо проверить наличие класса `menu-active-sub-item` у `li` внутри `sub-menu`.

Если класс есть, то нужно добавить класс `current-menu-parent` у `li` верхнего уровня.

Эта функция не работает как ожидается:

```
if ( $('li.nav-item').hasClass('menu-active-sub-item') ) {
    $(this).parents('li.menu-item').addClass('current-menu-parent');

}
```

Как это правильно добавить класс?

**UPD**

мой вариант такой:

```
if ( $('li.menu-active-sub-item') ) {
    $('li.menu-active-sub-item').parents('li.menu-item').addClass('current-menu-parent');
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что эта функция не работает?

Comment: Вангую, что "не работает" - в данном конкретном случае значит "не вызывается"

Comment: @Darth, скорее из-за того, что `li.nav-item` несколько `hasClass` проверяет только первый элемент, у которого действительно не класса active

Comment: попробуй вместо hasClass, сразу выбрать нужные элементы `$('li.nav-item.menu-active-sub-item')` тогда сразу от них можно идти к родителям, если они есть конечно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет нужды самому бежать по всем `li.nav-item` только для того, чтобы найти из них такие, у которых присутствует класс `current-menu-parent`.

Вместо этого нужно искать сразу нужные элементы, взять у них родителей, и присвоить нужный класс.

Это может выглядеть так:

```
$('li.nav-item.menu-active-sub-item').parents('li.menu-item').addClass('current-menu-parent');
```

Пример:

```js
$('li.nav-item.menu-active-sub-item').parents('li.menu-item').addClass('current-menu-parent');
```

```css
.menu-active-sub-item,
.menu-active-sub-item>.nav-link,
.current-menu-parent>.nav-link {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-active-sub-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-active-sub-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Все гениальное - просто )))

Comment: @MedvedevDev, на самом деле довольно простое решение задачи поиска всех элементов, которые содержат что-то, это найти что-то и взять нужных родителей

Answer (score 4):

В вашем коде в `$(this)` находится не искомывай вами элемент, а весь документ (если не прав в формулироваке, коллеги, просьба поправить меня).

Проверять несколько элементов нужно через `.each()`, тогда и `$(this)` уже будет относиться к проверяемому вами элементу:

```js
$('li.nav-item').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('menu-active-sub-item')) {
    $(this).parents('li.menu-item').addClass('current-menu-parent');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-active-sub-item,
.menu-active-sub-item>.nav-link,
.current-menu-parent>.nav-link {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-active-sub-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-active-sub-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">title2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. а если так сделать? https://jsfiddle.net/jnscLfjh/1/  Такой подход допустим?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova допустим. Этот как раз решение из ответа Grundy, но с предворительной проверкой на наличие искомых элементов

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, в это случае всегда будет заход в `if`, так как селекторы в jquery **всегда** возвращают объект, который эквивалентен true, при проверке, то есть если в твоем примере заменить `if ( $('li.menu-active-sub-item') ) {` на `if ( true ) {` ничего не поменяется

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде определяться наличие класса будет только у последнего объекта `$('li.nav-item')`, а требуется перебирать все (как уже писали) и определять есть ли класс хотя бы у одного.

```
$('li.nav-item').each(function() {
  const $navItem = $(this),
    $menuItem = $(this).parents('li.menu-item'),
    navItemIsActive = $navItem.hasClass('menu-active-sub-item');

  if(navItemIsActive) {
    $menuItem.addClass('current-menu-parent');
    return false; // так как достаточно одного совпадения, то цикл можно прервать
  }
});
```

Comment: добавь пояснения в свой ответ

Comment: Твой код работает не так, как хочет автор вопроса, посмотри какой элемент вернет closest, и какой на самом деле нужно вернуть

Comment: Не очень понял в чем отличие `.parents('li.menu-item')` и `.closest('li.menu-item')`? Кроме того, что мой вариант вернет только ближайшего родителя, а в задаче вернет всех.

Comment: В том, что closest может вернуть **себя**, а не родителя, если текущий элемент удовлетворяет селектору, что и происходит в данном случае

Comment: воу, да, не заметил, что классы одинаковые. Поправил

Comment: `break` нельзя использовать вне цикла или switch. `each` в данном случае обычная функция, и при использовании в таком виде как в ответе будет кинуто исключение: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: понедельник - день тяжелый.